# symfony isolate bundle to be possible for each team to work in its separate bundle

Tags: symfony, github, devops, software-design, software-distribution

I have a huge api wrote in symfony3 with several bundles(all bundles are included in the same git repo), we have multiple teams working each for its own bundle, my problem is: we have one branch by env, so, if a developer work on dev branch although all other teams use the same branch he can't integrates his own code on prod branch because all other changes made by others may be injected also on prod and that's very complicated situation to manage.
So how to do to splitup my app to be possible for every team to commit/push its own work on branch env without so complicated procedure?
What is the best architecture to use in this case, how to islolate each bundle to others using symfony? Or what you recemmand if you have already experiecned the same thing? Knowing that my devops platform is based on wercker CI it builds one big image docker with all symfony bundles and deploy it to amazon ecs.

Comment: Are you looking for feature branch workflow? No idea, your question makes no sense. And the state it's in right now, it's too broad for SO.

Comment: Ok, mister Alex, to ask question in other way that can make sens for you, if you are experiencing the same thing, what is the best archtitecture, branch workflow, deployment solution to use, to be possible for your teams to inject theire PRs and deploy theire changes easily.

Comment: Scenario described here is pretty common: you won't split code just because, maybe, you'll get less conflicts during merge. You split code because of many things (decoupling, microservices, "SRP" and so on...) IMHO, every dev should rebase its branch multiple time a day (if you have frequent integration in original branch) in order to avoid merge nightmare. Conflicts are part of this process and you can't avoid them even if you split the code in one line per git repo.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution to avoid conflicts but a solution to isolate a symfony bundle on a separated git repos. In order to avoid merging the others teams's work.
Some times just one team must inject theire changes on production, the problem here is they must rebase to avoid a multiple tens of commits (this is a one repo all others team commit in same branche develop) and in certain situations it's not possible at all, so what to do to simplify this process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use submodules or spliting up your app using git submodules or using composer structure, that's mean all your bundle must be required by composer when building app in your CI, and so you can continue your devops fluently

Comment: Nice, but submodules also can be also complicated in some situations more exactly during build process

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using microservice architecture, every bundle must be a project alone, so your teams can push theirs code on a separate git repo no need to have one big project in which everybody commits his changes to the same dev branch, that means each PR may contain all others developers changes. 
Microservices can be the solution, it's very expensive to install as an architecture but i think this is the best solution for such projects.

Comment: I think that is very expensive architecture to implement, that represent a revolution for me, I do not have time nor resources for it. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The previous micro-services solution that was given by @imane-bahiaoui seems to be a good choice especialy with the new version of symfony 4 which is a perfect for micro-services. But taking your comment into consideration I recommend splitting your project into several git repositories and use `composer` to bundle it all together as if it was one project during the build process in your CI server or on local environment, you must pay attention to semantic versioning of your bundles.

An example of this is the Laravel framework source code composer.json file:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/composer.json

```
"replace": {
    "illuminate/auth": "self.version",
    "illuminate/broadcasting": "self.version",
    "illuminate/bus": "self.version",
    "illuminate/cache": "self.version",
    "illuminate/config": "self.version",
    "illuminate/console": "self.version",
```

Comment: Can you provide me a real example?

Comment: you can take a look at some modern frameworks composer.json like the laravel framework: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/composer.json, take a look at the `replace` section

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot separate the code in different subprojects/bundles to be maintained in their own repository and separately required by composer, the easiest and cleanest way to handle bigish teams handling bigish features is to use git flow.

Basically it uses a separate branch for each new feature, created from and eventually merged back into the general dev branch when the feature is ready for staging/testing.

You can see a nice overview here

https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

You do not get code separation, but if you keep features well defined and have a solid architecture, merging should be quite controlled.

The extra upside is that the flow is supported by many tools

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using currently but it still a not sufficient solution, why?

All completed features live together in the same branch. Assuming that, commercial team want to inject feature X  to prod, at this time we have 15 completed new features on dev env, that mean we have to look for branch X in git history to inject it on prod env, that's far to be easy in reality. Because some other branchs more recents may be passed to prod so to inject X you must manage a very difficult rebase process. My gaol is to simplify this process as possible.

Comment: gitflow already suggests a solution for that. Only branches of features planned for the next release should be merged into the main dev branch. Check the 3rd diagram on the link

Comment: And if you do not really trust your teams to not do something stupid, perhaps you could use some fork and pull request flow instead of feature branches. This might also integrate nicely with your CI (as in pull only if tests pass etc)